# Softphone & Asterisk on same machine in centos?

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk & java application for voip project in centos.
Now i am trying to use open source softphone on same machine where asterisk present. I try pjsua but when ever asterisk on pjsua not work & when ever asterisk stop pjsua works...

Now i am also trying to find out in Asterisk there is App-Konference..is there way to fetch audio coming from 1 sip phone to asterisk & we can send it. like softphone do?

Means person who handle asterisk server he also talk with other sip phones...
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the port pjsua is listening on. Asterisk is listening on udp 5060 and your phone wants to listen on the same port.

Change the port to 5061 and you will be fine.

I do not understand the sacond part of your question.

What do you want to do exactely?

Comment: Thanks for Answer sascha.daniels, i wonder how it will work Asterisk work on 5060 & if 2 sip phones(hardware) communicate with help of Asterisk by port 5060, how as same will happen with 1 hardware sip phone with 5060 & 1 softphone with port5061 with help of Asterisk(& Asterisk & Softphone on same machine)? Where can i get technical answer?

Comment: Asterisk is listening on 5060

Normally every SIP Client (hard or soft) is listening and sending on 5060, but that does not need to like that.

That does not work on one machine. You can not bind two services on the same port.

When softphone is listening on 5061, it just makes a connection frmo 5061 to 5060 (asterisk). Asterisk will save IP and port as contact.

Now your hardphone is registering from port 5060 at your asterisk. Asterisk will save IP and port again.

Because asterisk knows on which ports its clients are listening, it can send the sip messages to the right port.
Clear enough?